# Issue Converting JPG to PNG and Compressing | PHP

Tags: php, png, image-compression

Essentially I would like to upload an image to a web server and also convert it from JPG to PNG with as much compression as possible.

The following is what I currently have to upload a JPG image from a mobile device:

```
<?PHP
  if(!empty($_FILES['uploaded_file']))
  {
    
    $path = "uploads/";
    $path = $path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
      echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']).
      " has been uploaded";
    } else{
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }
  }
?>
```

This works well but I must now convert the file to a PNG and compress - for this I have tried working with code like this, but I do not understand how to implement it and also add compression.

```
 $image = imagecreatefromjpeg( "image.jpg" );
 imagealphablending($image, true);
 imagepng($image, "image.png");
```

Is something converting and compressing possible?

Answer (score 0):

In official php documentation: https://www.php.net/imagepng

It is stated that the function signature for imagepng is:

```
imagepng ( resource $image , mixed $to = null , int $quality = -1 , int $filters = -1 ) : bool
```

Parameter quality:

```
- quality

    Compression level: from 0 (no compression) to 9. 
    The default (-1) uses the zlib compression default. 
    For more information see the » zlib manual.
```

Therefore when you save the image as PNG in below code, it's already compressed:

```php
 $image = imagecreatefromjpeg( "image.jpg" );
 imagealphablending($image, true);
 imagepng($image, "image.png");
```

If you want higher compression (i.e.: smaller size, worse image quality), then you just need to put higher number in quality parameter (closer to 9 = heavier compression)

```php
 $image = imagecreatefromjpeg( "image.jpg" );
 imagealphablending($image, true);
 imagepng($image, "image.png", 9); // heavily compressed
```

You need to be careful though that `imagejpeg` https://www.php.net/imagejpeg also have `quality` parameter, but that one ranges from 0 (worst quality, smaller file) to 100 (best quality, biggest file).